# Firefox vs Safari with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, safari

In Firefox, this code works like a charm...but in Safari, it doesn't execute...where am I going wrong?

```
$('#ul_stages li.stage').on('click', updateStageByClick);

function updateStageByClick() {
   var id = $(this).parent().attr('class').substr(6);
   var pid = $('form#data input[name=pid]').val();
   var stage = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/invite/stage",
     data: {project: pid, user: id, stage: stage},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: update
   });
   return false;
}

<ul id="ul_stages" class="stage_<?= $profile['user_id'] ?>">
   <li>SELECT STAGE:</li>
   <li class="stage_unviewed stage" value="0">Unviewed</li>
   <li class="stage_viewed stage" value="1">Viewed</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No surprisingly not @RocketHazmat

Comment: Can you post your `update` function as well?

Comment: Does the click event fire?  Does the AJAX request fire?  Do you know what part isn't running?  Put some `console.log`s into the click event to see if that's running.

Comment: update function is simply a batch processing mechanism we have for ajax requests...it doesn't fire no @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$('form#data input[name="pid"]').val();
```